# Insert many values to table in a shorter and cleaner method

Tags: mysql

I want to insert many values to a table with two columns of type INT.
I look for an easier and cleaner method to do it instead of using many insert into commands.
Here's my code:

```
insert into fpp_mapping values (311, 221)
insert into fpp_mapping values (321, 121)
insert into fpp_mapping values (3331, 2121)
insert into fpp_mapping values (3323, 12)
insert into fpp_mapping values (331, 111)
```

And there are about a hundred more lines.
Is there a way to insert those values with a loop with MYSQL?

Comment: If you want to use a loop you're talking about a program that can retrieve the integers for you and insert them in the database. Something like [PHP](https://www.php.net) perhaps?

Comment: To the 4 identical answers I will add that for 100 rows, the batch inserts will run approximately 10 times as fast.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like:

```
insert into fpp_mapping values 
(311, 221),
(321, 121),
(3331, 2121),
(3323, 12),
(331, 111);
```

At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can try batch insert like below

INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

Read the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing insert statement with columns definition you can write like below.

```
insert into fpp_mapping values (311, 221), (321, 121), ... , (331, 111);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the reference manual for [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) we can see that multiple values can be specified:

```
insert into fpp_mapping values (311, 221), (321, 121) ,
(3331, 2121), (3323, 12),(331, 111)
```